# $cordovaCapture.captureVideo Call Crashes Cordova App on iOS 10.1

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ios10, video-capture, ngcordova

I have a Cordova app (written for Android and iOS) that's been working fine in production with a fair number of users, including on iOS 10.0 after the necessary security tweaks a month or two ago. Now with the more recent 10.1 upgrades, (currently testing on 10.1.1) I find that attempts to call the video capture functionality completely crashes Cordova, without any option to debug from a JS-perspective. There is no issue on the Android side. This is just with the latest update to iOS, and there have been no code or plugin updates or changes.

We're using the most recent **cordova-plugin-media-capture** plugin, v1.4.0, with ngCordova. Calls to this plugin to take a photo via `$cordovaCapture.captureImage` work fine in iOS 10.1.1. It's just calls to `$cordovaCapture.captureVideo` which completely and instantly crash Cordova. I've looked at Xcode in case there are any new or out-of-whack settings and everything seems correct, so would welcome any suggestions on resolving this.

Earlier (a month or two ago) we resolved the new iOS 10 permissions issue using the **cordova-plugin-settings-hook** plug-in with these iOS settings (snippet shown) in config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Reason goes here...</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Reason goes here....</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Reason goes here...</string>
    </config-file>
```

I confirmed these settings using Xcode. The parameters we pass in to the actual call are as follows:

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo
({
    limit:      1,  // how many clips to record (iOS must be 1)
    duration:   300 // maximum length (in seconds) = 5 minutes
})
```

Hoping someone else managed to resolve the same issue and is willing to share the workaround.

Comment: FYI app was originally using Cordova v6.2.0. I upgraded to the latest v6.4.0 and retested, but am getting the same iOS issue.

Comment: For the two folks kindly suggesting I look at microphone permissions. I've dug further and that seems to be the reason it's crashing (from the crash report.) Something must be screwed up somewhere as I have both your config.xml settings included, and I can see on Xcode too that the reason string is present, yet the app doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: Tried keeping the microphone settings in config.xml, then `cordova clean ios` then rebuilding and running. Did the trick, and I can now record videos again. So underlying issue was microphone setting, but there was also something else screwed up in the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`, which is needed when you record a video.

The strange thing is, 1.4.0 version of the plugin should add all the UsageDescriptions, you shouldn't need the cordova-plugin-settings-hook, but for some reason it is not working if you needed to add that plugin.

On a clean new project with just the 1.4.0 media plugin it works as expected with no crash.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Greatly appreciated! Will look into that, and if resolves, accept answer. Kind of weird that we had to address permissions in 10.0, and everything worked then. Perhaps this permission is only enforced in 10.1.

Comment: Unfortunately did not resolve issue. (Still crashes.) Will +1 since this is a needed permission anyway.

Comment: Follow up... Crash log (from Xcode Device menu) showed missing microphone usage string was to blame for crash, even though they were in the Info section of Xcode. So, combination of adding the microphone setting and running a cordova clean ios command finally did the trick. As you were the first to suggest the microphone setting, and you even used the word "clean" :) will mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10 update, plugin has to be added along with variables having permission description to it. 
Use the below code in your config.xml of cordova project.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="1.4.0">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To take videos"/>
    <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To record voice while taking videos"/>
    <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To provide photo browsing."/>
</plugin>
```

This would solve the problem.

Refer ios quirks: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: As you can see elsewhere in this ticket, combo of microphone setting plus a cordova clean ios command did the trick. jcesarmobile pointed out the microphone setting first so will award there, but this was a nice answer too, for someone who doesn't want to use the settings-hook plugin that we are already using so did +1.